# How to send email in android in a AsyncTask class

Tags: android, multithreading, email, android-asynctask

How do I send an email in android within a AssyncTask whenever I run the application the following error occurs:

> calling startactivity() from outside of an activity context requires
>   the flag_activity_new_task flag

### This is my class

```
private static final class SendMailPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, Integer>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private String _email = "shotmail@gmail.com.br";

    private SendMailPhotoTask(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }       

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Bitmap... data) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = data[i];
            String name = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if (bitmap != null) SendMail(name + ".jpg", bitmap);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    private void SendMail(String name, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try{
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);  
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { _email });
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Alerta de Movimento");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Foto em anexo");

            //need this to prompts email client only
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Send Mail", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

use addFlags.

```
   emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the type of context that you pass in the parameters.

Instead of writing:

`new SendMailPhotoTask(getApplicationContext())`

You should write:

`new SendMailPhotoTask(YourActivity.this)`

Or if you call it from a fragment:

`new SendMailPhotoTask(getActivity())`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the one @user184994 indicates above: you need to supply an instance of `Activity` (and not `getApplicationContext()`) as the context to call `startActivity()` on.

However, I should point out that this code is an improper (or at least unnecessary) usage of `AsyncTask`: since you will launch an activity (e.g. GMail) for sending the e-mail, why would you need a background thread?

If what you need is to send e-mail *without user intervention* then you need a different approach (probably using JavaMail or a similar library). Take a look at [javamail-android](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/).

Comment: My application captures photos if a certain action occurs, each captured photo has to be sent by email without user intervention or handling, so I'm using an AsyncTask.

Comment: Then you have to use a completely different approach. This code will just launch multiple gmail windows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using this form of sending emails without Intent.

[Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)